# Erro de PK durante processo Assíncrono de procedure

Tags: sql-server, assincronismo

Pessoal me deparei com uma situação onde consegui resolver o problema porém gostaria de saber mais a fundo como funciona o UPDLOCK. Eu tinha uma situação que basicamente era assim dentro de uma procedure:

```
SET @MAX = SELECT MAX(NRDOC) FROM TABLE1 WITH(NOLOCK)
SET @MAX2 = SELECT MAX(NRDOC) FROM TABLE2 WITH(NOLOCK)

IF @MAX2 > @MAX
 SET MAX = MAX2

INSERT INTO TABLE1 (NRDOC) VALUES (@MAX+1)
```

Na realidade existiam mais campos no insert e era um insert into x select ..., mas o problema era no numero do documento pois era PK na tabela 1. O problema ocorria pois a procedure era executada mais de 1 vez ao mesmo tempo com outros parametros, por conta de ser dentro de um processamento assincrono do C# e de 15 arquivos processados uns 4 ou 5 ocorriam problema pois no MAX eram retornados os mesmos valores, eu resolvi o problema trocando o WITH(NOLOCK) por WITH(UPDLOCK) por conta de uma pesquisa que fiz na internet, porém eu não entendi muito bem por traz do processamento o que ele faz, e se também existiria uma outra forma de resolver isso com outro acesso a tabela. Esse e outros procedimentos estavam dentro de uma transaction

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDLOCK
```

Especifica que bloqueios de atualização serão usados e mantidos até que a transação seja concluída. `UPDLOCK` utiliza bloqueios de atualização apenas em operações de leitura no nível de linha ou de página. Se `UPDLOCK` for combinado com `TABLOCK`, ou se um bloqueio em nível de tabela for usado por outro motivo, um bloqueio (X) exclusivo será usado.

Quando `UPDLOCK` é especificado, as dicas em nível de isolamento `READCOMMITTED` e `READCOMMITTEDLOCK` são ignoradas. Por exemplo, se o nível de isolamento da sessão for definido como `SERIALIZABLE` e uma consulta especificar (`UPDLOCK`, `READCOMMITTED`), a dica `READCOMMITTED` será ignorada e a transação será executada usando o nível de isolamento `SERIALIZABLE`.

[fonte:msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187373(v=sql.120).aspx)